# Windows Compat ID OS Feature Descriptor does not show uo in registry

Tags: windows, usb, registry, enumeration

I am working on a WINUSB project using the ATXMega128A4U microcontroller. I have success using the ASF and extending it with WCID functionality. However I now experiment with a much lighter driver for the USB module, and now I can't get it to work. Windows query for the Compatible ID Feature Descriptor and I return the exact same stream of bytes as in the ASF project. However the Compatible ID newer shows up in registry. Windows also query for the extended OS Feature Descriptor where I return the DeviceInterfaceGUID (properly formatted), but that is also not showing up in registry. Any clue what could make Windows ask for descriptors but not accepting properly formatted replies?